# I have a problem in evaluating flux integral, and I will list the complete question below.(SOLVED)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the flux integral $\iint_S{\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{n}ds}$, where $\mathbf{F}(x,y,z) = \lt{3xy^2,xcos(z),z^3}\gt$ and S is the complete boundary surface of the solid region bounded by the cylinder $y^2+z^2=2$ and the planes $x=1$ and $x=3$. S is oriented by the outward normal vector.

Actually, I have known that this problem can be solved by applying the Divergence Theorem to convert the double integral into triple one under the cylinder coordinate. But I would like to directly evaluate it by parametrizing S. My understanding about the way to parametrize the surface is: Since the planes $x=1$ and $x=3$ have formed an extension in $x$-axis, what I need to do is to parametrize the boundary of the cylinder, which ensures I have parametrized the whole surface given in the question.

So the parametric form of S is $$\mathbf{r}(\theta,x)=\lt{x,\sqrt{2}sin(\theta),\sqrt{2}cos(\theta)}\gt,x\in{[1,3]},\theta\in{[0,2\pi]}$$

Thus, we can obtain $$\mathbf{r}_x=\lt1,0,0\gt,\mathbf{r}_\theta=\lt0,\sqrt{2}cos(\theta),-\sqrt{2}sin(\theta)\gt$$

Thus, we can obtain $$\mathbf{r}_x\times\mathbf{r}_\theta=\begin{vmatrix} \mathbf{i}&&\mathbf{j}&&\mathbf{k}\\1&&0&&0\\0&&\sqrt{2}cos(\theta)&&-\sqrt{2}sin(\theta)\end{vmatrix}=\lt{0,\sqrt{2}sin(\theta),\sqrt{2}cos(\theta)}\gt$$

I know that we have should divide the cross product vector we just had to obtain the unit normal vector which is outward. However, we have the formula in parametric form:
$$\iint_S{\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{n}}ds=\iint_S{\mathbf{F}\cdot(\mathbf{r}_x\times\mathbf{r}_\theta)dA}$$

Thus, $$\mathbf{F}=\lt{6xsin^2(\theta),xcos(\sqrt{2}cos(\theta)),2\sqrt{2}cos^3(\theta)}\gt$$
$$\mathbf{F}\cdot(\mathbf{r}_x\times\mathbf{r}_\theta)=\sqrt{2}xsin(\theta)cos(\sqrt{2}cos(\theta))+4cos^4(\theta)$$
Thus$$\iint_S{\mathbf{F}\cdot(\mathbf{r}_x\times\mathbf{r}_\theta)dA=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^3[\sqrt{2}xsin(\theta)cos(\sqrt{2}cos(\theta))+4cos^4(\theta)]dxd\theta}$$

But I am not sure if it is correct. Thanks for taking your time to just look at it for a little while.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is off topic (too broad, missing context). Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof that is in doubt, and why so.

Comment: You are missing the flux across the two disks at the end of the cylinder. Be careful to pay attention to the orientations of those disks, too.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you are correct and this integral is not that hard to evaluate once you notice that the integral of the first term reduces to zero (it would be easier to integrate wrt $\theta$ first). Indeed $x \to sin(x) cos(\sqrt 2 cos(x))$ is an odd periodic function, so its integral from $0$ to $2 \pi$ will be equal to $0.$ To convince yourself of this fact, simply make the change of variables $t = 2 \pi - \theta$ in $\int_0^{2 \pi} \sqrt{2}xsin(\theta)cos(\sqrt{2}cos(\theta)) d \theta.$ In order to evaluate the second part of the integral, I have the following suggestion: write $$cos^4(\theta) = cos^2(\theta) cos^2(\theta) = \frac{1}{4} (cos(2\theta) + 1)^2 = \frac{1}{4}(1 + 2 cos(2\theta) + cos^2(2\theta)) = \frac{1}{4}(1 + 2 cos(2\theta) + \frac{cos(4 \theta) + 1}{2}) = \frac{3}{8} + \frac{cos(2 \theta)}{2} + \frac{cos(4 \theta)}{8}$$
and evaluate the integral in these simpler terms. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: This is correct for only a part of the problem.

Comment: Sorry, @TedShifrin, what do you mean precisely?

Comment: The OP forgot to do the flux across the two disks that are part of the boundary of the region.

Comment: Ah, right, you are absolutely correct. Fortunately, those are even more trivial.

Comment: Sorry, @TedShifrin, does it means that my parametric equation does not include the two disks at the end of the cylinder? Could you please explain it again in detail? Thanks so much!

Comment: How could a cylindrical shape include the two ends? Graph your parametric equations. Stop and think.

Comment: @TedShifrin I got it and made such a mistake! Thanks so much!!!